# backbone event fired many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have an EditorView subview associated with one `Model` that renders a series of form elements (input checkbox, textarea).

My ListView creates ***one and only one*** Editor sub view. ListView creates the EditorView by way of  `new EditorView(model: this.model). render();` on a click of an item in the ListView.

That works great.

But, when an event is attached to the Editor subview

```
  // Bind to all properties in the view
  events: {
     "click input.isactive":  "editActive"
  },
```

The event gets fired multiple times...once per ***previously*** loaded EditorViews. As if the html for many was still present. But checking the DOM (in Firefox) shows the html for only one EditorView.

I use .html(string) in EditorView, which I thought would replace the previous html within the 'el' element.

```
     var compiledTemplate = _.template( Template, data ); // Merge model with template
     this.$el.html( compiledTemplate );  // replace the previous html if any. ?? OR NOT!! SOAD
```

Thanks

The EditorView

```
  el: ".editor",

  tagName: "ul",

  className : "striped",

  events: {
     "click .isactive":  "editActive"
  },

  render : function() {

     var data = {
       item: this.model,
       _: _ 
     };

     var compiledTemplate = _.template( Template, data ); // Merge model with template
     this.$el.empty().html( compiledTemplate );  // replace the previous html 
     return this;
  },


  editActive: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = this.$('.isactive').prop('checked'); // property of input checkbox
        alert('click'+x);

        var y = this.model.set('Active', x);
  }
```

Comment: Jquery docs "use .empty().html( string ) instead of .html(string) so that the elements are removed from the document before the new string is assigned to the element." Didnt actually function as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone attaches handlers to a root element of a view, so callbacks are registered multiple times when you create several views with the same root element. It uses [event bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling) to detect events that were triggered on a child element. The problem is with this line:

```
el: ".editor",
```

Even if you remove all of the contents of `.editor`, handlers for the element itself will stay. You need either to delete it, or if you want to keep it you can use the `undelegateEvents` method of the view before creating a new one: it will remove previously attached event handlers.

Comment: oh. i see. that means while the html element is gone. the event may still remain...

Comment: @GabeRainbow no, not exactly. It's because event handler is attached to another element not to `.isactive`, but to `.editor`, even when you write `click .isactive`. And you never delete `.editor`.

Comment: ok. i see. so you need to call undelegateEvents in the initializer or elsewhere.

Comment: @GabeRainbow this will only remove `.editor` contents, not `.editor` itself.

Comment: @GabeRainbow right before `new EditorView`, on a previous instance of `EditorView`.

Comment: got it. i was thinking that backbone needs a GarbageCollector or autorelease function. so one might put it into destroy(), close() or dealloc(). thank you sir.

Comment: @GabeRainbow: Stop doing `el: ".editor"`, let the view create its own `el` and call `view.remove()` when you're done with it. Then recreate the view if you need it again. That should kill 90% of your zombie problems.

Comment: then one needs to bind in the superview. that seems less encapsulated.